# jQuery put a break in line that is out of screen

Tags: jquery

I got some long text to display in jQuery grid column, like '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10'

After '8' screen ends and doesn't display '9 10'

Is there a way to put some sort of dynamic break there, so it would show like

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
9 10
```

Code:

```
@model PhonebookSB.Controllers.HomeController.getinform

<html style="height:100%">
<body lang="RU" style="height:100%" >
        <style>
        A {
            color: #000;
        }

        html, body {
            height: 95%;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        infoName = '@Model.infoName';
        $('#grid').jqGrid({
            hidegrid: false,
            url: "/Home/GetInfo/" + @Model.infoIdOut, page: 1,
            datatype: 'json',
            jsonReader: {
                repeatitems: false
           },
            mtype: 'GET',
            afterInsertRow: function (rowid, aData) {
            },
            colNames: ['infoid', infoName],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'infoId', index: 'infoId',  hidden: true, sortable: false },
                { name: 'infoText',  align: 'left', sortable: false, hidden: false}
            ],
            height: '100%',
            rowNum: 1,
            viewrecords: true,
            subGridOptions: {
                openicon: "ui-helper-hidden"
            },
            loadComplete: function () {
                gridId = ("grid");
                gridWidth = $('#gbox_' + gridId).parent().width();
                gridHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
                $('#' + gridId).jqGrid('setGridWidth', gridWidth);
                $('#' + gridId).jqGrid('setGridHeight', gridHeight);

                gridId = "tree";
                gridHeight = $(window).innerHeight();

                $('#' + gridId).jqGrid('setGridHeight', gridHeight);
            }
        });

        $('#tree').jqGrid({
            url: '/Home/infoTree/',
            mtype: 'GET',
            treeGrid: true,
            treeGridModel: 'adjacency',
            ExpandColumn: 'infoName',
            ExpandColClick: true,
            treedatatype: 'json',
            datatype: 'json',
            colNames: ['infoId', 'infoName'],
            colModel: [
                        { name: 'infoId', index: 'infoId', hidden: true, sortable: false },
                        { name: 'infoName', index: 'infoName', hidden: false, sortable: false }
            ],
            onSelectRow: function (ids) {
                if (ids != null) {
                    data = jQuery('#tree').getRowData(ids);
                    jQuery("#grid").setGridParam({ url: "/Home/GetInfo/" + ids })
                        .trigger('reloadGrid');
                }
            },
            caption: ''
        });

        $("#grid").jqGrid("hideCol", "subgrid");
        gridId = "grid";
        gridWidth = $('#gbox_' + gridId).parent().width();

        $('#' + gridId).jqGrid('setGridWidth', gridWidth);

        gridHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
        $('#' + gridId).jqGrid('setGridHeight', gridHeight);

        gridId = "tree";
        gridWidth = $('#gbox_' + gridId).parent().width();

        $('#' + gridId).jqGrid('setGridWidth', gridWidth);
        gridHeight = $(window).innerHeight();

        $('#' + gridId).jqGrid('setGridHeight', gridHeight);
        $('#' + gridId).closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view")
            .children("div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv")
            .hide();
    });
</script>

<div class="span3" style="font-size: 12.0pt">
            <div class="specialtree" style="height:100%; width: 100%">
                <table id="tree" style="height:100%; width: 100%"></table>
            </div>
    </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span9">
                <table id="grid" style="height:100%; width: 100%; word-break:break-all"></table>
            </div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make a table width equal to screen width (100%) and then use word break: break-word.

Comment: Make fiddle or put your code here, it will help us for answer, this can simply done by css, but if you put your code or fiddle then it will more clear.

Comment: there is no word-break: break-word, only break-all, i tried to use it but it still tries to wright everything as one line, no matter that there's not enough place for that...

Answer (score 0):

I could not find proper way to split jqGrid column, but You can try overflow for displaying your result, It is most used and proper way to display large number of column because number of column may be 10 or more then 10 .

```html
<div  style="overflow:auto;width:100px">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>      <td>1</td>      <td>1</td>      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>      <td>1</td>      <td>1</td>      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>      <td>1</td>    
    </tr>   
    </table>
</div>
```

Check this tutorial for more detail about overflow. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: I almost solved problem by making 
<style> 
#grid { word-wrap: break-word } 
</style>, now I got all text on the screen, but it began to spred words in the middle..

Comment: @AHTOHPolsky break-word will break the word where it will find space. that's why i suggest you to use overflow. using this you can fix screen width to display data and if large data found then scroll bar automatically enable. check this for more: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp